# Как сделать запрос на выборку данных с нескольких столбцов одной таблицы из коллекции Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Имеется модель `Author` и таблица `authors` с двумя полями `author_surname` и `author_name`.
При поиске по каталогу авторов нужно сделать выборку по фамилии или по имени автора в таблице.
Вопрос такой с помощью какого метода в коллекции можно сделать выборку типа `SELECT * FROM authors WHERE author_surname=$author_surname OR author_name=$author_name`
В query builder можно использовать два метода `DB::select('author')->where('author_surname', '=', $author_surname)->orWhere('author_name', '=', $author_name)`.
Но как это сделать используя коллекции полученную через модель `Author` ведь там есть только метод `where()`.

---

```
AuthorController.php 

public function index(Request $request)
{
    if (!empty($request->sort)) {
        $authors = Author::all()->sortBy('author_surname');
    } elseif (!empty($request->search)) {
        $authors = Author::all()->where('author_surname', $request->search);
    } else {
        $authors = Author::paginate(15);
    }
    return view('authors.index', compact('authors'));
}
```

В файле `authors.index` пагинация, сортировка по фамилии автора и должен присутствовать поиск по фамилии или имени автора.

Comment: [orWhere()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#or-statements)

Comment: В коллекциях нет такого метода как orWhere().

Comment: Передайте в `where` масив значений, например `Author::where([['author_surname', $request->search], ['author_name', $request->search]])->get()`

Comment: метод where() ведь первым аргументом принимает string!

Comment: @NickDeniel В вашем случае нужно просто выборку правильно делать, а не вытягивать всё, а потом фильтровать коллекцию.

Answer (score 0):

Метод orWhere() был правильным решением, стоило только убрать метод all() и последним методом вызвать get()

```
$authors = Author::where('author_surname', $request->search)->
        orWhere('author_name', $request->search)->get();
```